Wrote a GetParameters typescript type extractor but it's not working
I am learning typescript, and I found this GetParameters type, but it's not working for me. I am getting the following error:
Parsing error: ';' expected.eslint
Generic type 'GetParameters' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

what am I doing wrong?
type GetParameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = 
   T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;


const getPerson = (name: string, age: number) => { 
  return {name, age}
};

function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}

type PV = GetParameters(typeof getPerson)

See error:


this should work.
You're using GetParameters which is a type as if you're using a function (i think you meant to use these "<>" instead), so what you need to do is pass the typeof getPerson as a generic parameter type, you can't pass a value as a generic type, only types can be passed, if you want to dive deeper you can read this section from the docs.
